# CSS: absolute position inside centered relative div issue

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have an issue with absolute and relative positioning.

Im trying to center a relative DIV that contains all absolute div. The problem I have is when I try to center my relative DIV, my absolute div "#mainForm" get shrink (height issue).

In the html below, if you remove the position and margin attribute on the "#main" class, you will see that the page layout is displayed correctly.

How can I center my relative div without affecting my absolute divs ?

** What im trying to achieve is to have only my #mainForm that is scrollable.
   My sideBar, mainHeader and mainFooter must be "fixed". Client requirements...

Thanks David

Here is my CSS and HTML.

- xhtml11.dtd doctype.

```
<head>      
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <style>
        html {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size: 8pt;  
        }

        *, *:before, *:after {
          box-sizing: inherit;
        }

        #main {
            position: relative;  /* if I removed this, page is not centered but mainForm height is ok */
            margin: 0 auto;     /* if I removed this, page is not centered but mainForm height is ok */
            width: 960px;       
        }

        #sideBar {    
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
            width: 180px;   
        }

        #mainContent {   
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            bottom:0;
            right:0;
            left:180px; /* Width of #sideBar. */
            width: 780px;         
        }

        #mainHeader {
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            height:40px;
            width:100%; /* Mandatory. With is 100% of parent div. */

            border: 1px solid blue; /* For developing purpose */
        }

        #mainForm {
            position: absolute;
            overflow:auto;   
            top:40px;
            bottom:40px;
            width:100%; /* Mandatory. With is 100% of parent div. */

            border: 1px solid yellow; /* For developing purpose */
        }

        #mainFooter {
            position: absolute;
            bottom:0;
            height:40px;    
            text-align:right;
            width:100%; /* Mandatory. With is 100% of parent div. */
        }

        #topSideBar {
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            background-image: url("../images/pas/contactLogo.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;   
            height:110px;
            width:100%; /* Mandatory. With is 100% of parent div. */
        }

        #middleSideBar {
            position: absolute;
            top:110px;
            height:200px;
            width:100%; /* Mandatory. With is 100% of parent div. */
        }

        #bottomSideBar {
            position: absolute;
            bottom:0;
            height:100px;
            width:100%; /* Mandatory. With is 100% of parent div. */
        }

        /* clearfix */
        .clearFixaa:after {
            content: ".";
            display: block;
            clear: both;
            visibility: hidden;
            line-height: 0;
            height: 0;
        }               
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="main" class="clearFix">

        <div id="sideBar" >
            <div id="topSideBar">
                <!-- Contact Logo css backgound. -->
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div id="middleSideBar">
                middleSideBar
            </div>
            <div id="bottomSideBar">
                bottomSideBar
            </div>              
        </div>

        <div id="mainContent">
            <div id="mainHeader">
                mainHeader
            </div>
            <div id="mainForm">

                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                mainForm
                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                mainForm
                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                mainForm
                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                mainForm
                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                mainForm
                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>                                                           
            </div>
            <div id="mainFooter">
                mainFooter
            </div>      
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning for **general layout** is a very poor and inflexible choice. There are much better options and more flexible options available.

Comment: This code is just wrong. I even tried to make a https://jsfiddle.net/yhudwxux/ but it doesn't work. Please provide a reasonable sample and I'll try to help you :)

Comment: I know absolute positioning is not the best choice but i can't figure out a way to do it i without that.  My header and footer needs to be fixed and my "mainForm" needs to be scrollable with a dynamic height. A other option i saw is to resize dynamically my mainForm with javacsript and use all relative positioning but I don't really like mixing css and js for layout..

Comment: If you replace the css class by this: #main {
    width: 960px;
}  you will see the "layout". By centering the main div, the mainForm is shrink.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yhudwxux/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your css. This will do the work:

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
#main {
    position: fixed;
    /* if I removed this, page is not centered but mainForm height is ok */
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* if I removed this, page is not centered but mainForm height is ok */
    width: 960px;
    height: 960px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#sideBar {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width: 180px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    /* For developing purpose */
}
#mainContent {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:180px;
    /* Width of #sideBar. */
    width: 780px;
    height: 100%;
}
#mainHeader {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    /* Mandatory. With is 100% of parent div. */
    border: 1px solid blue;
    /* For developing purpose */
}
#mainForm {
    position: absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    top:40px;
    bottom:40px;
    width:100%;
    /* Mandatory. With is 100% of parent div. */
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    /* For developing purpose */
}
#mainFooter {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:40px;
    text-align:right;
    width:100%;
    /* Mandatory. With is 100% of parent div. */
}
#topSideBar {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-image: url("../images/pas/contactLogo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:110px;
    width:100%;
    /* Mandatory. With is 100% of parent div. */
}
#middleSideBar {
    position: absolute;
    top:110px;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    /* Mandatory. With is 100% of parent div. */
}
#bottomSideBar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    /* Mandatory. With is 100% of parent div. */
}
/* clearfix */
 .clearFixaa:after {
    content:".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

The trick was to fixed the #main div and position it with left:0 and right:0. I had a static height for the main div, feel free to remove it and add height where you need like for the sidebar.

Comment: Thank you. The only concern I have is that the mainForm height is dynamic.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the answer as valid so the subject can be closed.